# What happens if both players get to 7 points at the same time?

Tags: android-netrunner

Let's say the runner and corp are both at 4 points.  The runner is tagged.  The runner runs on archives and accesses 3 [Quantum Predictive Models](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09007) and a [Restructured Data Pool](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02016).  This would put both players at 7 points.  Who wins?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The runner chooses who wins (and presumably chooses themselves) with the order they access they access the cards.  From the Rules Reference:

> When the Runner accesses cards in Archives, the Runner turns
>   all cards faceup in Archives, then accesses and resolves each
>   card in Archives one by one in the order of their choosing.

Also, as @LScottJohnson Points out in the comments:

> "If the Runner scores an agenda that gives him seven or more points, he immediately wins the game, even if he would otherwise access more cards."

Comment: And note the further exposition in the rules: "If the Runner scores an agenda that gives him seven or more points, he immediately wins the game, even if he would otherwise access more cards."

Answer (score 2):

The example in the question and the question from title itself don't really connect, as Zags' answer shows - in that scenario both players never have 7 points simultaneously.

More fitting example would be: swapping [Global Food Initiative](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09026) for [Merger](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10114) using [Exchange of Information](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10092), and in that case per Damon Stone ruling **the game ends in a tie** [Source:](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10114)

Another similar scenario might occur in a game with [Harmony Medtech](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05001). While [Employee Strike](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09053) is in effect both players can reach 6 points without ending the game, then if Employee Strike ends, Harmony Medtech ability becomes active again and ends the game in a tie.